# How to prove that the sequence of random variables converges to a random variable?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

If $Z_1,Z_2,\cdots,Z_n$ are random variables such that $Z(\omega)=\lim_{n \to \infty}Z_n(\omega)$ exists $\forall \omega \in \Omega$, then $Z$ is also a random variable.

I was reading a book on probability which provided a very terse proof which I cannot follow. Here is what the author writes. 
$$\{Z\leq x\}=\bigcap_{m \geq1} \bigcup_{n \geq 1} \bigcap_{k\geq n}\left \{Z_k \leq x+ \frac{1}{m}\right\}$$

So the author claims that as $Z_k$ is measurable, so is $Z$ as the set $\{Z\leq x\}$ can be written as countable union/intersection of measurable sets.I have spent considerable time trying to figure out why the two sets a equal.

Can someone give me a hint as to how should I go about proving it? It turns out that this "clue" or "solution" is incomprehensible to me.
Thanks.

Comment: @MikeEarnest:My bad, I just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this is saying is that the limit $Z(\omega)$ is at most $x$ is the same as, for all $\epsilon>0$, the sequence $Z_n(\omega)$ being eventually less than $x+\epsilon$. They used $\frac1m$ instead of $\epsilon$ to allow for a countable union.

Here's how you can prove it rigorously. Suppose $Z(\omega)\le x$. Then for all $\epsilon>0$ (in particular, for all $1/m$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$), there is an number $n$ so $k\ge n$ implies $|Z_k(\omega)-Z(\omega)|<\frac1m$, implying $Z_k(\omega)\le Z(\omega)+\frac1m\le x+\frac1m$. This shows $\omega\in\bigcap_m\bigcup_n\bigcap_{k\ge n}\{Z_k\ge x+\frac1m\}$.

Now, suppose $\omega$ is in the RHS. Assume (by way of contradiction) that $x<Z(\omega)$. Choose $m$ large enough so $x<x+\frac1m<Z(\omega)$. Since $Z_n(\omega)\to Z(\omega)$, for large enough $n$, $Z_n(\omega)$ is eventually greater than $x+\frac1m$. But this is impossible, since $\omega$ being in RHS implies $Z_n(\omega)$ is eventually $less$ than $x+\frac1m$ for large enough $n$. Thus, we must have $Z(\omega)\le x$, proving the other inclusion.

Comment: What I fail to grasp is the use of the two intersections and the unions. I mean $\omega \in$ "RHS" iff $\forall m \exists n$ s.t $\forall k \geq n $,$x \in \{Z_k \leq x+ \frac{1}{m} \}$ .This implies $\omega \in \{Z \leq x\}$. To prove the converse(subset inequality) we say that $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ s.th $ \forall n\geq N$,$\omega \in \{Z_n(\omega)\leq x \} $ which implies that $\omega \in $ "R.H.S" . Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I was having troubles figuring out why the two sets were equal at the first place

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks, so I was right. I just saw that you added the rigorous proof.T hanks for your time, I am grateful

Answer (score 1):

Here an other way to understand it by using the definition of limsup. As I am just a student i hope that it is correct and that it will help other people to have a better understanding.

1- First of all let recall the $Sup$ definition of a sequence of r.v.: $Sup(\omega)=Sup\left \{ \omega \in \Omega :X_n(\omega)<a : \forall n \geq 1 \right \}=\left \{ \omega \in \Omega : \bigcap_{n \geq 1}^{} X_n(\omega) < a\right \}$, and this is a r.v as a countable intersection of r.v.
Now we define the following sequence of r.v. $V_n(\omega) = Sup\left \{ X_n(\omega) : \forall k \geq n \right \}$.Note that $V_n(\omega)$ is a decreasing sequences so $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }V_n(\omega)=X(\omega)$.
Hence we can writte: $\left \{ \omega \in \Omega: V_n(\omega)<a \right \}=\bigcap_{k\geq n}^{}\left \{ \omega \in \Omega: X_n(\omega)<a \right \} \Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\left \{ \omega \in \Omega: V_n(\omega)<a \right \}=\bigcap_{n \geq1}^{}\left \{ \omega \in \Omega: V_n(\omega)<a \right \}=\bigcap_{n \geq1}^{}\bigcap_{k\geq n}^{}\left \{ \omega \in \Omega: V_n(\omega)<a \right \}$
The set: $\bigcap_{n \geq1}^{}\bigcap_{k\geq n}^{}\left \{ \omega \in \Omega: V_n(\omega)<a \right \}$ is a r.v. as the countable intersection of r.v.

2-But by assumption $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)$ so: $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }X_n(\omega)=\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty }X_n(\omega)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }V_n(\omega)=X(\omega) \Rightarrow \left \{ \omega \in \Omega :X(\omega)<a  \right \}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\left \{ \omega \in \Omega: V_n(\omega)<a \right \}=\bigcap_{n \geq1}^{}\bigcap_{k\geq n}^{}\left \{ \omega \in \Omega: V_n(\omega)<a \right \}$

In conclusion $X(\omega)$ is a r.v. as we succeeded to give a countable description of the event: $\left \{ \omega \in \Omega :X(\omega)<a  \right \}$ Q.E.D.

Comment: A much simpler and shorter proof. Thank you!